# Show Alert through Corona SDK similar to UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput of iOS SDK

Tags: uialertview, alert, coronasdk

I am developing an apllication Corona SDK where I need an Alert popup similar to alert with style UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput in iOS (shown below). I will take password to verify for giving access to some restricted area of my application.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how can i do it through Corona SDK. My application will deploy on iOS and Android devices.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona's native.showAlert() API call does not support that feature.  It sounds like something that would be a good be a good feature request though.